# In UIGrid always show the tree row header

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

In a UIGrid where grouping is applied, I need to show the group tree row header always even though there is no data for that group. See the image below that represents the idea.

Please advice.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set treeRowHeaderAlwaysVisible to true. This will do the job.